# node installed in docker container but not npm

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I have this DockerFile

```
FROM docker:17.12.0-ce as static-docker-source

FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ARG CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=335.0.0
ENV CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=$CLOUD_SDK_VERSION
ENV PATH "$PATH:/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/"
COPY --from=static-docker-source /usr/local/bin/docker /usr/local/bin/docker
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get install -qqy \
    curl \
    gcc \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    openssh-client \
    git \
    gnupg && \
pip install crcmod && \
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)" && \
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python-extras=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-cbt=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    kubectl && \
gcloud --version && \
docker --version && kubectl version --client
VOLUME ["/root/.config"]

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash -

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential pkg-config libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev

ADD requirements.txt /
ADD requirements-prod.txt /

ADD submodules /
RUN python --version
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements-prod.txt
```

when I run node --version it returns v10.24.0 (I think it should be 8.x.y ....).
And when I run npm --version it returns bash: npm: command not found

Shouldn't node install npm too ?

Thanks

Comment: You're installing an old nodejs version:

Comment: `RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -`

Comment: Try using `RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -`

Comment: So actually, removing FROM python:3.8-slim-buster and adding python via apt without changing anything else seems to do the trick. I know this is an old version of python but this an old project and I do not want to upgrade it at risks of causing breaking change...

Comment: Glad you solved it like this, why not create an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed it by changing my DockerFile.

I deleted FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as I read that having multiple 'FROM' on a dockerfile could cause conflict. And I installed python with apt like this:

```
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get install -qqy \
    curl \
    gcc \
    python3.8 \
    python3-pip \
    python3.8-dev \
```

However, it is not perfect to me because I now have python3.6.x under python 3, python 2.7.x under python and I must specified python3.8 when I need it...

---

My new DockerFile:

```
FROM docker:17.12.0-ce as static-docker-source

FROM ubuntu:18.04

ARG CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=335.0.0
ENV CLOUD_SDK_VERSION=$CLOUD_SDK_VERSION
ENV PATH "$PATH:/opt/google-cloud-sdk/bin/"
COPY --from=static-docker-source /usr/local/bin/docker 
/usr/local/bin/docker
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get install -qqy \
    curl \
    gcc \
    python3.8 \
    python3-pip \
    python3.8-dev \
    apt-transport-https \
    lsb-release \
    openssh-client \
    git \
    gnupg && \
pip3 install crcmod && \
export CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(lsb_release -c -s)" && \
echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && \
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - && \
apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y google-cloud-sdk=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python-extras=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    google-cloud-sdk-cbt=${CLOUD_SDK_VERSION}-0 \
    kubectl && \
gcloud --version && \
docker --version && kubectl version --client
VOLUME ["/root/.config"]

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash -

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential pkg-config libcairo2-dev 
libjpeg-dev libgif-dev
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
RUN python --version
ADD requirements.txt /
ADD requirements-prod.txt /

ADD submodules /
RUN python --version
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements-prod.txt
```

Comment: Edit queue is full.. can you please edit your answer to be more descriptive like this?

```
So I fixed it by changing my DockerFile:
 1. Removing `FROM python:3.8-slim-buster`
 2. Adding python via apt without changing anything
```